# post запрос в javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

Прошу помочь с отправкой POST запроса на сервер при помощи javascript. В Python смог написать скрипт, все отлично работает

```
import requests as requests

def get_records():
    data_map = {'key': '12', 'machine_id': 'test'}
    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'cookie': 'mos_id=CllGxlx+PS20pAxcIuDnAgA=; session-cookie=158b36ec3ea4f5484054ad1fd21407333c874ef0fa4f0c8e34387efd5464a1e9500e2277b0367d71a273e5b46fa0869a; NSC_WBS-QUBG-jo-nptsv-WT-443=ffffffff0951e23245525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; rheftjdd=rheftjddVal; _ym_uid=1552395093355938562; _ym_d=1552395093; _ym_isad=2'
    }

    r = requests.post(url='http://gift.wowsugar.ru/api/config/test.php', data=data_map, headers=header)
    print(r.text)


get_records()
```

В javascript написал что-то похожее, но выдает только ошибку 500.

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

let  data_map = {'key': '12', 'machine_id': 'test'};

let response = fetch('http://gift.wowsugar.ru/api/config/test.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'cookie': 'mos_id=CllGxlx+PS20pAxcIuDnAgA=; session-cookie=158b36ec3ea4f5484054ad1fd21407333c874ef0fa4f0c8e34387efd5464a1e9500e2277b0367d71a273e5b46fa0869a; NSC_WBS-QUBG-jo-nptsv-WT-443=ffffffff0951e23245525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; rheftjdd=rheftjddVal; _ym_uid=1552395093355938562; _ym_d=1552395093; _ym_isad=2'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data_map)
}).then(res => res.status)
  .then(status => console.log(status));

console.log(response)
```

Прошу прощения, если глупый вопрос, я только учусь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заработал такой скрипт

```js
import http from 'http';

const data = JSON.stringify(
  {
    'key': '5555', 'machine_id': 'test'
  }
);

const options = {
  hostname:'gift.wowsugar.ru',
  path:'/api/config/test.php',
  method:'POST',
  body: {
    key: '12', machine_id: 'test'
  },
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'cookie': 'mos_id=CllGxlx+PS20pAxcIuDnAgA=; session-cookie=158b36ec3ea4f5484054ad1fd21407333c874ef0fa4f0c8e34387efd5464a1e9500e2277b0367d71a273e5b46fa0869a; NSC_WBS-QUBG-jo-nptsv-WT-443=ffffffff0951e23245525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; rheftjdd=rheftjddVal; _ym_uid=1552395093355938562; _ym_d=1552395093; _ym_isad=2'
}
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) =>{
  let body='';
  console.log('status code: ', res.statusCode)

  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
  })

  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Body: ', body)
  })
})

req.write(data)
req.end();
```